# Can I use windows f1-micro instance in Google cloud platform - always free usage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I read the document from Google:

[Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits?hl=ru)

> ## Google Compute Engine
>
> Scalable, high-performance virtual machines
>
> 1 f1-micro instance per month (US regions only, excluding Northern Virginia)
>
> 30 GB-months HDD, 5 GB-months snapshot
>
> 1 GB network egress from North America to all region destinations per month (excluding China and Australia)

There is only type of instance (f1-micro), but not OS. Can I use Windows or SUSE Linux?

Answer (score 4):

I understand you want to use Windows or SUSE Linux operating system in an f1-micro instance and want to know whether it will still be always free usage or not.

To answer your question, SUSE Linux and Windows servers are considered as [premium images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#premiumimages) and all prices for premium images are in addition to the charges for using a machine type. Thus, this extra charge will be incurred when these operating systems are used making the setup not free. You can check the charges for one specific combination of setup from the [price calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).

I hope this helps.